# Weird behavior while iterating over ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, foreach, arraybuffer

I have two ArrayBuffers, the first (`A`) is a subset of the other and only contains long IDs. The second (`B`) contains objects of a case class `g` which has the ID as an attribute. Now I want to loop over `A` in order to remove all objects in `B` matching the corresponding ID as well as the ID from `A`. I use the following method

```
def removeID (ID:Long) {
  B.find(_.ID == ID) match {
    case Some(s) => 
      B.remove(B.indexWhere(_.ID == ID))
      A -= ID

   case None => sys.error("Cannot remove ID $ID")
}
```

}

I'm a little bit confused since the error I get now is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot remove ID 0
```

which does not make sense since there is no 0 in `A` or `B`. I tried to figure out what exactly happens during the loop it is obvious that

```
for(ID <- A) {removeID(ID)}
```

just applies the `removeID` method on every 2nd element until it reaches the end of `A` and then tries to find the ID `0` which does not exists.

Does somebody know where this behavior comes from?

Edit: So the problem is not the removal of an ID (it happens like it should) but rather the iteration over the ArrayBuffer which does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get that error because there is no ID 0. So the `case None` part gets executed.
But I suggest you use filter instead.

```
def removeID(ID: Long) {
  B = B.filterNot(_.ID == ID)
  A -= ID
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Right, ID `0` does not exist but then why is `removeID` applied to 0 when `A` does not contain an ID equal to `0`? Where does the 0 come from? I have no idea.

Comment: Is the line `for(ID <- A) {removeID(ID)}` the only place where removeID is being called? I'm guessing it's called again somewhere else. Or maybe you have some code somewhere that adds an ID to A without also adding it to B.

Comment: It is called on other places but when I just call it once, the behavior is the same.

Comment: The problem is that you remove elements from an ArrayBuffer WHILE you are iterating over it with a for comprehension. You should never do that as it can lead to unpredictable behaviour. To find out the exact reason you'd have to look at the source code of ArrayBuffer.foreach, since a for comprehension is being translated to a call to foreach.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. I figured it out just before you wrote your comment. Thank you so much!